# How to reset damaged column structure in SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

If trying to resize column width in SceneBuilder, column structure appears completely damaged

https://youtu.be/0p5WqzhaTaA

How to fix / handle?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 8.1.1

Comment: You can file an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues?status=new&status=open), reporting what you have noticed, including version, OS, Java version, and how to reproduce it.